# UIScrollView displays wrong location

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a UIScrollView that contains a UITextView in which I have a bunch of static text. As soon as the amount of text in the TextView got larger than a page, when the ViewController is launched, the text is scrolled to the last page.

I have tried adding

```
ScrollWindow.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1), animated: false)
```

to the ViewDidLoad() and/or the ViewWillAppear() methods, but that has had no effect.

So I tried adding:

```
        textContainer.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(0,0,1,1), animated: false)
```

in one or both of those same methods, and still, the text is stubbornly NOT scrolling to the top as I'd like.

I guess the better approach here might be to put all this info into a formatted web page and then include that in the app and use a WebViewer instead but that just seemed like overkill.

I can't see why this won't scroll properly.

Comment: Have you tried using content offset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @TroyT for pointing me in the right direction.

Used a bunch of print() statements to see what was going on and on loading the TextView component, the contentOffset was always going to (0, 481) for reasons I still can't explain. However, this fixed it:

```
textContainer.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0,-150), animated: false)
```

I have no idea why setting it to (0,0) doesn't work, but after falling around with it for a bit, -150 seems to be the sweet spot.